# How to set a custom complexity limits for sonar in java?

Tags: java, sonarqube, complexity-theory, cyclomatic-complexity

Is there a way to set complexity limits for sonar?
I prefer very simple codes (at most one if or loop), but I cannot find a setting like `sonar.cpd.java.minimumtokens` or `sonar.cpd.java.minimumLines` exist for code duplications (and does not seem to work, but that will be another question).

I would like to reduce the cyclomatic complexity limit for methods, and also the maximum number of methods in one class. For the latter, a line limit would be okay.
How can I set those complexity limits?

Answer (score 1):

There is a few Java rules targeting cyclomatic complexity provided with SonarQube. The only way to configure them is to use a dedicated Quality Profile. By default, the *SonarWay* quality profile uses fixed thresholds. However, these rules are parameterizable, and you can configure them as soon as you create a quality profile other than the default SonarQube's *SonarWay* profile. You will then have to configure your project to rely on this new Quality Profile, rather than *SonarWay*.

For reference, have a look at the following rules:

- [squid:MethodCyclomaticComplexity](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/coding_rules?open=squid%3AMethodCyclomaticComplexity&rule_key=squid%3AMethodCyclomaticComplexity): Methods should not be too complex (default threshold: 10)
- [squid:ClassCyclomaticComplexity](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/coding_rules?open=squid%3AClassCyclomaticComplexity&rule_key=squid%3AClassCyclomaticComplexity): Classes should not be too complex (default max: 200 - deprecated rule)

I would also recommend to have a look at another complexity-related rule:

- [squid:S3776](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/coding_rules?open=squid%3AS3776&rule_key=squid%3AS3776): Cognitive Complexity of methods should not be too high

This rule is relying on the concept of [Cognitive Complexity](https://www.sonarsource.com/docs/CognitiveComplexity.pdf), designed in order to remedy Cyclomatic Complexity’s shortcomings and produce a measurement that more accurately reflects the relative difficulty of understanding, and therefore of maintaining methods, classes, and applications.